# Oracle 11g R2 - dbms_xmldom: need to repeatedly append DOMDocumentFragment copies to different locations in a DOMDocument

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2, xmldom

I populate a DOMDocumentFragment, with the aim of copying its contents to a number of locations in a target DOMDocument.

I have tried pretty much everything I can think of to achieve this but it's a case of epic fail. The following simplified working code illustrates one method I have tried that I would expect to work:

```
declare
  vTargetDoc         dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;
  vFragDoc           dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;
  vFrag              dbms_xmldom.DOMDocumentFragment;
  vAttachPointNodes  dbms_xmldom.DOMNodeList;
  vElt               dbms_xmldom.DOMElement;
  vTmpN              dbms_xmldom.DOMNode; 
begin
  -- create the target document
  vTargetDoc  := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument(xmltype('<TargetDoc><AttachPoint></AttachPoint><AttachPoint></AttachPoint></TargetDoc>'));
  -- create the source document to contain the fragment to be attached repeatedly
  vFragDoc    := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument();
  -- create the fragment
  vFrag       := dbms_xmldom.createDocumentFragment(vFragDoc);
  -- append element "A" to the fragment
  vElt        := dbms_xmldom.createElement(vFragDoc,'A');
  vTmpN       := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(dbms_xmldom.makeNode(vFrag),dbms_xmldom.makeNode(vElt));
  -- identify all the attach points in the target document
  vAttachPointNodes := dbms_xslprocessor.selectNodes(dbms_xmldom.makeNode(dbms_xmldom.getDocumentElement(vTargetDoc))
                                                    ,'/TargetDoc/AttachPoint'
                                                    );
  -- iterate through the attachpoints
  for i in 0 .. dbms_xmldom.getLength(vAttachPointNodes) - 1 loop
    -- import and attach the fragment to the current attachpoint
    vTmpN := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(dbms_xmldom.item(vAttachPointNodes,i)
                                    ,dbms_xmldom.importNode(vTargetDoc
                                                           ,dbms_xmldom.makeNode(vFrag)
                                                           ,true
                                                           )
                                    );
  end loop;
  -- print out the resultant target document XML
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_xmldom.getxmltype(vTargetDoc).getclobval());
end;
```

The noteworthy items in the code above are:

1. I create the fragment in a different document
2. On each attach point I import the fragment as a node (with deep = true)

The aim in this approach is to use importNode to copy the contents of the fragment from the source document as many times as I need to attach it in the target document.

The good news is that it does successfully copy the contents of the imported fragment to each required attach point.

The bad news is that it also appends a copy of the imported fragment at the end of the document as shown in the following illustrative output:

```
<TargetDoc>
  <AttachPoint>
    <A/>             EXPECTED
  </AttachPoint>
  <AttachPoint>
    <A/>             EXPECTED
  </AttachPoint>
</TargetDoc>
<A/>                 UNEXPECTED
<A/>                 UNEXPECTED
```

(the 2 FragmentContents duplicates appended on the end of the document are unexpected)

I can't figure out why it is creating the duplicates using this method, and neither can I find any other method that works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `vAttachPointNodes` isn't getting the top-level `TargetDoc` node multiple times, as well as the actual points you expect? It might be helpful to create a small self-contained example, though I realise that isn't going to be trivial in this case...

Comment: @AlexPoole - thanks for your input! I have replaced the oriiginal contents above with simplified working piece of code that illustrates the problem I am having. Hopefully it will be prove helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the repeated calls to `dbms_xmldom.makeNode(vFrag)`; you're doing that again each time round the loop, which creates another new node, and as at that point you aren't calling `appendChild()` it seems to stick it somewhere that looks a bit random.

You can refer to the result of your first call, `vTmpN`, instead:

```
  for i in 0 .. dbms_xmldom.getLength(vAttachPointNodes) - 1 loop
    -- import and attach the fragment to the current attachpoint
    vTmpN := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(dbms_xmldom.item(vAttachPointNodes,i)
                                    ,dbms_xmldom.importNode(vTargetDoc
                                                           --,dbms_xmldom.makeNode(vFrag)
                                                           ,vTmpN
                                                           ,true
                                                           )
                                    );
  end loop;
```

which produces:

```
<TargetDoc>
  <AttachPoint>
    <A/>
  </AttachPoint>
  <AttachPoint>
    <A/>
  </AttachPoint>
</TargetDoc>
```

In this example it doesn't seem to matter that you're reassigning `vTmpN` - the next time round the loop that's still holding the node you want. You may prefer to have a separate variable to be safe (or clearer) though.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer! ...it appears that I have been under a misapprehension as to what "makeX" does. My understanding has been that it behaves similarly to a cast statement, "presenting one type as another", but it appears from your answer that it in fact creates a new node, which then - lacking a defined attach point - is appended to the document root. I would rush to the documentation to look deeper ...but dbms_xmldom is sadly probably the worst documented piece of Oracle functionality I have come across. (and yet it is so powerful). Thanks again.